# trying to use a combination of countifs to determine number of transactions per customer in excel

Tags: excel-formula, data-analysis

So I have store transaction data including one column for customer ID and one for transaction date.

I am trying to figure out how to count the number of transactions for each customer ID based on transaction date. There are 45000 rows in each column, so I cannot manually enter each customer ID into the formula.

Chat GPT was of no help. lol

Happy to supply the data if needed to help.  Thanks in Advance!

I've tried to use countifs with a boolean comparitor between cells, but of course as soon as it switches to a new customer ID, the combination of ID and date becomes unique again and so it doesn't work.

I've tried to concatenate ID and date and use the unique function, but again, this does not give me transactions per customer, only a total of total shops.

I also tried sumproduct in combination with countif on the concat data but this returned an error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the board.  Could you add a sample of data to your question as text so it can be copied and pasted into Excel.  The Edit button is just below the tags at the bottom of the question.  This link will help in formatting the data table:  https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Comment: Also worth adding a table showing what result you're expecting and what your `COUNTIFS` formula looked like.